# Basic Ruby on Rails Question about routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

I have a controller without any related model. This controller is to span some information from various models. I have lots of actions there, which define certain views on the page. What would be the best way to organize routes for this controller?

What I would like is to have /dashboard/something point to any action in the dashboard controller. Not actions like new/edit but arbitrary (showstats, etc).

With trial and error I made something like this:

```
map.dashboard 'dashboard/:action', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => :action
```

Now it is possible to access those URLs using the helper:

```
dashboard_url('actionname')
```

This approch seems to be working ok, but is this the way to go? I am not quite sure understand, how are the helper method names generated. How to generate same helper names as in basic controllers "action_controller_url" ? That would be more generic and made the code more consistent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to specify the `:action => :action` key in the route, this is done for you already. Other than that, how you've done it is fine.

You can also specify it as a symbol: `dashboard_url(:actionname)`, but you already knew that ;)

Comment: Is there a way to reformat the helper, or provide a custom one? IE: actionname_dashboard_url instead dashboard_url(:actionname)?

Comment: You would need to define a new route for every single one. The singular route method is a couple of characters longer, but results in less code overall.

Comment: Yeah, I though theres some automatic mechanizm, which generates the helpers on the fly, but since thats not the case, I will just stick to the dashboard_url(:actionname) convention.

Answer (score 2):

If you want helper methods for all your dashboard actions you should specify them all using named routes, for example:

```
map.example_dashboard 'dashboard/example', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'example'
map.another_dashboard 'dashboard/another', :controller => 'dashboard', :action => 'another'
```

Then rails will generate one _url and one _path helper for each named route. I prefer your approach, though, it's more flexible, and simple.

Comment: Wouldn't the index page for the OrdersController and ClientsController be a better place to serve the "dashboard" of these?

Comment: Definitely, I was just making up action names for my example. I'll change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

> How to generate same helper names as
>   in basic controllers
>   "action_controller_url" ?

```
  map.action_controller(
    'action_controller',
    :controller => 'controller',
    :action => 'action',
    :conditions => { :method => :get }  # You can restrict the HTTP reqs allowed
  )
```

Comment: This isn't really the answer. If I will have 50 actions, then I will have to copy this code 50 times or create some werid loops over map...